# $http - Angular post parameters and get json from PHP

Tags: php, json, angularjs, http

Im new in Angular and even newer using $http. What I'm not able to get is the following_

- post parameters using $http (required parameters for the PHP to perform the call)
- Get a JSON as response to that call

This is what I got so far:

$http call:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var parametres = $.param({ nomWS: ws, servidor: ip, query: param, idCamping: dadesCamping[0], forceRenew: renew});       

var url = './api/functions.php?function=callWS_JSON'; 

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: parametres,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(data) {            
    console.log('success');
    deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

What the php who recieves the call is to retrieve a content using the parameters sended via $_POST[] and get the json using:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($url);        
echo $fileContents;
```

If I set the parameters manually in the PHP script it outputs a valid JSON string, but when I echo it in order to retrive it in my javascript(angular) code i get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
at Object.parse (native)
at Vb (http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:14:208)
at e.defaults.transformResponse (http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:64:454)
at http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:64:215
at Array.forEach (native)
at r (http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:7:280)
at pc (http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:64:197)
at c (http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:65:400)
at C (http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:94:187)
at http://domain/lib/angular/angular.js:95:350
```

If I echo something before the echo of the content I dont get the error and the console outputs the following:

```
test
{&quot;clientesPresentes&quot;: {&quot;cliente&quot;:...
```

(Cutted the output, but the idea is clear)

I asume that the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` is because of the output. And im pretty sure that the problem is about headers and content-type. Tried to find the parameters to perform a post call and get json content as answer but I dind't managed to find out. So any help would be really apreciated.

Thanks in advance

PD: tried to set `header('Content-type: application/json');` in my php file but I get the same `SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` error

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The quotes are turned to html entities and this ofcourse is not valid data (not to mention proper json format). Check the php construction of your data object before json_endoding it

Answer (score 0):

where are comming the params?

I use this way.

```
var $scope.someData = {
   'param1': 12,
   'param2': 33
};

//someData var can also be set inside a form

<input type="text" ng-model="somedata.param1" >

//post and get available
$http.post('url.php' , $scope.someData)
    .success(function(res){
      ;
             })
    .error(function(error){
      ;
    });
```

and in the php file get the variables this way

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $data->param1;
```

Comment: the problem is not on getting the parameters on my php script, that works fine. the problem is to return the json string to the $http call, there is when everithing goes wrong.

To be more precise, the string I amb trying to output is already in a JSON format, and I echo it using just a echo. I think the problem is right there, I tried using json_encode etc and still fails

Answer (score 0):

You probably have unescaped strings in you JSON file.